# Deep link that opens up Slack and auto-fills text in the message box

Tags: deep-linking, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I wish to implement this feature that allows users to use a deep link into a Slack's channel on their phones or computers, and pre-fill some texts in the message box.

I have read through the documents and didn't find relevant solutions.

I was hoping to find a link that looks like:

```
https://slack.com/app_redirect?app=A1BES823B?text=prefilled_message
```

Comment: This is not how deep links work in Slack. But if you want to send a message via HTTP link why not use incoming webhooks? https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

Comment: Yes I agree. Webhook is the temporary workaround I found. The reason I wished the deep link to do the job is to reduce server load.

Answer (score 4):

[Deep Links](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking#slack_apps) in Slack do not support including a text message. You can only open a channel.

But you can use [incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) to send messages to a channel on Slack.

Or if you want to provide that exact functionality you can always build your own app to do it.