# Deep link to Slack to open direct message and pre-populate the message box

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, slack, slack-api

I am making a React Native app and deep linking the slack app.
I was able to open a conversation with a particular user with the help of

```
slack://user?team={TEAM_ID}&id={USER_ID}
```

as mentioned in their [docs for deep linking](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking#open_a_direct_message).

**Is there any way for me to open the conversation and pre-populate the message?

Or create a slack channel with team members?**

Comment: Of course. Just use the API to create a channel and send a message and then redirect the user with a deep link. Or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Can you please send me some examples/tutorials? And when you say 'use the API' what should I use? Do I have to make a Slack bot and then call the postMessage API?

Comment: yes you have to make a slack bot in order to get access to the API. you find lots of examples here: https://api.slack.com/tutorials

Comment: alternatively you could send messages using an existing incoming webhook. Only works if the workspace has an "old style" webhook installed though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878825/slack-incoming-webhook-sends-as-my-user?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep link that opens up Slack and auto-fills text in the message box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875947/deep-link-that-opens-up-slack-and-auto-fills-text-in-the-message-box)

Answer (score -2):

```
  Linking.openURL("slack://user?team={TEAM_ID}&id={USER_ID}&body=hello world");
```

I have not tried this and I am unsure whether it will work or not!
If not then if there is a [slack sdk](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk) in react native then only it will work. Else linking is limited to few functionalities only.

Comment: NO this will not work. The slack app does not handle body parameter.