# How to create a direct link to a specific Slack channel and prepopulates specific text

Tags: hyperlink, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am trying to easily allow users to use a deep link into a Slack's channel on their phones or computers, and pre-fill some texts in the message box and directs them to a specific channel

I have read through the documents and didn't find relevant solutions.

I was hoping to find a link that looks like:

https://slack.com/app_redirect?app=A1BES823B?text=prefilled_message

I have looked into webhooks but just wondering if something like would be possible without having ownership of the workspace, hence the limitation with webhooks.

https://slack.com/app_redirect?app=A1BES823B?text=prefilled_message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no deep link support for a channel message. The only available approach is to use a permalink of it. You can generate permalink URLs using https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.getPermalink

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep link that opens up Slack and auto-fills text in the message box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875947/deep-link-that-opens-up-slack-and-auto-fills-text-in-the-message-box)